# array in bash script

Tags: arrays, bash

i have a below script:

```
for (( i=0; i <= ( ${#arr1[@]} - 1); i++ )); do
  if [[ ${arr1[i]} > 100 ]]; then 
    echo "=> x"
    iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.162.1 -j DROP
    exit
  else
    echo "=> y"
  fi
done
```

In my array, no element > 100, all output must be "=> y". 
when `arr1[i]=1`, it's OK. output: "=> y"
But when `arr1[i]=5` or anything is not 1, it has a problem, output "=> x"

I think my problem is here `if [[ ${arr1[i]} > 100 ]]` but I dont know how to edit it. :(

Help me correct it . please . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with what you've done:

1. You need to say `if [[ ${arr1[$i]} > 100 ]]; then`  (note that it should be `$i` instead of `i`).
2. Saying `if [[ ${arr1[$i]} > 100 ]];` is **incorrect**.  This performs a **lexicopgraphic** comparison and isn't quite what is intended.  Either say:

   `if [[ ${arr1[$i]} -gt 100 ]]; then`

   or

   `if (( ${arr1[$i]} > 100 )); then`

Comment: The first one is not a problem. From `man bash`: *"The subscript is treated as an  arithmetic expression"*.

Comment: @TrungTrung You can find more information about conditional expressions [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions).

Answer (score 4):

You want either:

```
if (( ${arr1[$i]} > 100 )); then
```

or for POSIX shells that don't support `(())`, you can use:

```
if [[ ${arr1[$i]} -gt 100 ]]; then
```

[Here is a good list of other comparison operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html).

Comment: @TrungTrung See the link at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `-gt`, greater than

Comment: please refer to abs guide http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22313

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't use `i` for anything other than subscripting the array, it will be simpler to iterate over the *values* of the array directly:

```
for value in "${arr1[@]}"; do
    if (( value > 100 )); then
        echo "=> x"
        iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.162.1 -j DROP
        exit
    else
        echo "=> y"
    fi
done
```

This includes another option for correctly comparing two integer values, the `((...))` command, which provides a context where `>` can be used for numerical comparison instead of string comparisons.